# The penetrating power of ultrasonic waves

Tags: homework-and-exercises, acoustics

The penetrating powers of ultrasonic waves and other audible sounds are given as P1 and P2 respectively.Then P1 > P2. But how? Edit- So basically, I'm unable to imagine that,how high frequency plays role in more penetration in a medium compared to lower frequency sound wave of the same amplitude(i.e same pressure/density variation),same speed. These two waves have a different energy per unit volume, hence different intensities,since same speed. But why sound wave with lower frequency dies first compare to high frequency sound wave. (Sorry for my English and Physics knowledge if anything wrong written here.)

Comment: You need to provide a lot more detail.

Comment: So you are asking why high frequency ultrasound is absorbed more quickly than lower frequency ultrasound?

Comment: *Then P1 > P2.* That does not follow from the previous sentence, which says nothing about frequency.

Comment: Ultrasound - frequency > 20kHz. Audible sound waves - <20kHz.

Comment: I really can't understand the approach of the site. By the way, I have a hint for anybody who sees this question.  Consider the matter as a bunch of balls connected by springs (of course different matter different structures) then try to propagate an elastic wave through them.

Answer (score 1):

Why ultrasound absorption depends on frequency turns out to be a hard question to answer. Most of the interest in ultrasound is medical. There is lots of information about how attenuation affects the usability of ultrasound. For example, [Ultrasound—biophysics mechanisms](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1995002/).

But this is the only paper I found on why. It is paywalled. [The Mechanism of the Absorption of Ultrasound in Biological Materials](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/5008039). The abstract says

> 1. Absorption of sound in solutions of macromolecules has been found to be comparable in magnitude and similar in frequency dependence to that of tissues and blood. The absorption has been shown to arise through a relaxation process. Several experimental observations suggest that the relaxation may be related to the protein-water interactions. 2) The absorption of sound in normal blood, although predominately a molecular process, has in addition a component arising from the relative motion between the cells and the plasma. 3) In certain tissues, the experimental evidence points out again the importance of direct molecular absorption. This may be modified to some extent in inhomogeneous tissues where there is the possibility of selective absorption arising at macroscopic discontinuities.

Another place ultrasound matters is in SONAR. Absorption matters there too. Perhaps if you Googles SONAR absorption you might learn more.

Comment: I have edited my question, hope it's more clear now.